# Python import interaction

Tags: python, import

Well. I have a main file with a class in it. I have another file, where i wanna store functions (for the sake of simplicity), which use functions of that class. And I wanna import the second file into the first one, so i can use those functions in main file. And that's where I encountered a problem.

If I'm just importing the second file into the first one, I have an error which says that in second file the class is not defined. 
If I'm importing the first file into the second one AND the second one into the first one, I have an error in main file, which says that function I defined in second one doesn't exist.

That's the simpliest variant I can get. File 1:

```
import random
import Test2

class randoms():
    def __init__(self):
        pass
    def random_shit():
        a=random.randrange(19)
        return a


WTF= randoms()

Test2.printer()
```

File 2:

```
import Test

def printer():
    print(Test.WTF.random_shit())
```

Answer (score 0):

First off some python customs: usually classes are defined with capital letters:

```
class Randoms():
    pass
```

The problem is in file 2 and the fix will fix both errors for both files you define the object WTF in file 1 and then use it in a function. Basically you are using a variable which doesn’t exist inside the function. What you should do is initialize the object WTF inside the function you would like to use:

```
def printer():
   WTF = Test.randoms()
   print(WTF.random_shit())
```

You can remove the initialization inside the file 1.
Hope this helps.

Comment: Actually, it's not working. Still, when I call Test2.printer() it's show me an error "module 'Test2' has no attribute 'printer'"

Comment: Did you call the file 2 Test2.py? Also check that you are actually importing the right module and not another module (for example a module that you have installed in your environment called Test2).

Comment: yep, everything called as it needed, Test and Test2, and there is no any other Test2 or Test, and I even tryed (just in case) and put __init__ in folder.